# 17.10 and GNOME: Change default sound device

Tags: gnome, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

How can I change the default sound device?

I have a laptop with a docking station.  The dock has built-in SPDIF and analogue outputs but there is never anything connected to them and I still want it to use the built-in speakers in the laptop.  But every time I connect it to the dock, it automatically switches to the dock's analogue output and I have to manually change it back to the built-in speakers.